# jQuery getting text content of a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, dropzone.js, parents

I am trying to write a delete function in Dropzone.js. In order to do that I need the id of the file the way it was uploaded.

I tried to get a property of an object with no success. Now I am trying to use jQuery to get the value or text content of the span that has it.

[image]

this is the screenshot of the structure. The jQuery code I am trying is:

```
var loooot = $(".dz-filename").parents('span').text();
```

To be more specific I am trying to get the number 1_1477778745352 (which is a time stamp).

The Dropzone code is as follows:

```
<script>

var listing_id = "1"; 

// these are the setting for the image upload
Dropzone.options.pud = {
acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
uploadMultiple: false,
paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
maxFilesize: 1, // MB
addRemoveLinks: true,
maxFiles: 10,
renameFilename: function (filename) {return listing_id + '_' + new Date().getTime();},
init: function() 
{
this.on("removedfile", function(file) 
  { 
  var loooot = $("span", ".dz-filename").html();
  alert(loooot);
  });
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: `file.name` should keep name of file in callback of `removedfile`

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, but it returns the name of the uploaded file BEFORE it is renamed. After renaming I can see the ney name when I hover over the image thumbnail, but I cannot get then new renamed name.

Comment: But you could save it to dropzone, after upload as i do

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this use JQuery's `.text();` to get inner text
Update: use this with DOM `.ready()` like that.

Deep selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var fname = $("#pud .dz-filename span [data-dz-name]").text();
});
```

OR (if your form is dynamic)

```
function get_fname(){
return $("#pud .dz-filename span [data-dz-name]").text();
}
```

Then use `get_fname();`

Comment: Is your form dynamic?

Comment: This part is dynamic.

Comment: How is that dynamic? created from ajax or on click or..?

Comment: When I upload 10 images, every one of them gets the structure you see in the screen shot. They do not exist until images are not uploaded.

Comment: So you must wait for images loading then use `var f = get_fname();` as updated above

Comment: I don't know why but even using the fname solution I am getting an empty variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126979/discussion-between-mamdouh-freelancer-and-sandor).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var loooot = $("span", ".dz-filename").html();
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/o9zjv2p4/).

```js
var loooot = $("span", ".dz-filename").html();
alert(loooot);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dz-filename">
  <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Since you are setting the text dynamically it may happens that jquery read the HTML before that you set it, to prevent this you have to call this function after the timestamp as a callback (i can't help you without seeing how you set the `span` text).
So do something like:

```
function setSpan(callback) {
    // Set your stuffs

    // Call the callback
    callback();
}

function getText() {
    // I'm the callback witch get the html
}

//Onload
setSpan(getText());
```

**EDIT**

For dropzone you can use [`queuecomplete`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-queuecomplete) that start a function after the queue, i'm not an dropzone expert but i suppose:

```
init: function () {
    this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
        //Get span html
        alert("All files have uploaded ");
    });
  }
```

Comment: The variable loooot comes back as Undefined

Comment: It might be returning Undefined as Dropzone is created dynamicly. Your example works because it is static. This is my best explanation. Would you b able to modify your answer so it works with dynamicly created elements?

Comment: I've edit the question, but you have to show me how you set the timestamp or you could build the function with a callback

Answer (score 0):

It becomes undefined because dropzone works dynamicly, use this:

```
$('body').find(".dz-filename").find('span').text();
```

Best way to do this is to declare dropzone:

```
//first declare somewhere variable
var my_drop;

// then on creating dropzone:
my_drop = new Dropzone('.dropzone', { 
/* your setup of dropzone */ 
});
```

Then you can retreive information about files with this:

```
my_drop.files[0].name
```

The `[0]` represent's first file, you can loop through them if there's more then one.

Comment: If that's  the case, starting at the `body` won't help much. One can not get what is not there.

Comment: It is on body, it were just created after dom ready, so you can't get it with just class name of `dz-filename`

Comment: Then you shall define your Dropzone with variable and use the dropzone: `dropzone_variable.files[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

The working solution I found is this:

```
init: function() 
  {
  this.on("removedfile", function(file) 
    { 
    var loooot = $(file.previewElement).find('[data-dz-name]').text();
    alert(loooot);
    });
  }
```